# New Activity after login always in view

Tags: java, android-studio

When  my app starts it open new activity(FirstActivity) always both in success login or unsuccessful.I would like to open new Activity only when i have a successful LOGIN.

Below my code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {
        if (result != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding another `if condition` inside `if (result != null) {}` :

```
      if (result.getString("message").equals("what u get when successfully login")){
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
      }
      else{
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "login failed")
      }
```

Comment: Sorry i tried your code but i have always in view the "unable to retrieve any data from server" in view.

Comment: How doyou decide login is successful or not ?

Comment: you need to remove 
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent); 

and add above code

Comment: How do you decide login is successful or not ?

Comment: perhaps Do i have create a new Java class for login check? I thought that this code checked my successful or not.

Comment: yeah u can move that logic to another class. But what could be the result when login success ?  is this message relate to login success or failed. as I mention in above answer. u can check that.